# Is it possible to use Mirror API to recursively check for annotations during annotation processing

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation, annotation-processing

Suppose I have a class structure like :

```
@MyAnnotationOne
class A { 
    private String id;
    private B b;

    public static class B {
        private C c;

        @MyAnnoationOne
        public static class C {
            @MyAnnotationTwo
            private String annotatedString;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using annotation processing to generate code. If I'm processing @MyAnnotationOne, then using the Mirror API I can get all the fields in class A and class C.

I want to know if there is any way I could find if any of the fields in class A, going down the hierarchy contain the annotation @MyAnnotationOne or @MyAnnotationTwo. Finding any one would be enough.

I tried looking for a solution but I found some saying that since the annotation processing happens in a pre-compilation stage, the information might not be available. Please let me know if there's any solution that you might know. It'd be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure whether annotations are retained into runtime or not.  You annotate your own annotation type with the `java.lang.annotation.Retention` meta-annotation, specifying one of the values from the enum `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy`.

> `RUNTIME` Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.
>
> `CLASS` Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.
>
> `SOURCE` Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

**EDIT**
If you are building an annotation processor:

- your code is running during that (pre) compilation phase, so all annotations should be present.
- Mirror API is deprecated, see `javax.lang.model...` and `javax.annotation.processing`

If you override `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor.process()` you receive a `RoundEnvironment` with methods for getting model `Element`s, including sets filtered by specific annotation types.  And given an `Element` you can `getEnclosedElements()` and on those `getAnnotation(annotationType)`.